# how i can get accept language header from user?

Tags: python, django

i am developing a multi language website for that i need to get HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE for translating the messages in other languages.

Comment: You use an API to fetch information from a public listing. For example: https://github.com/propertyshelf/mls.apiclient

Answer (score 0):

Function django.utils.translation.get_language() returns the language used of the current thread. [https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language][1]